# How can I get the greatest product in an array of integers?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

This is not for a homework. It's just a part of a monthly algorithm exam for engineers in our company. The exam is done. I failed and this was the part of the problem that stumped me. Though it is not required to pass, it has an effect on your yearly bonus on how well you do in these algorithm exams.

So, given an array of integers, find the greatest product you can get using its elements. This is not the actual problem, just a tiny part of it.

The constraints are:

```
3 <= size_of_array <= 8
1 <= integer_in_array <= 9
Libraries are not allowed (e.g. Integer.max, Arrays.sort, etc...)
```

The initial solution I've thought of was to sort the array in descending order. Take the greatest value in the array then multiply it to the remaining integers.

Suppose, we have an array:

```
int[] arr = {3, 6, 5, 4};
sort(arr); // array becomes {6, 5, 4, 3}
int product = getProduct(arr);
```

In the getProduct method, I have:

```
int getProduct(int[] arr) {
    int maxVal = arr[0];
    int multiplier = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(multiplier == 0) {
            multiplier = arr[i];
        } else {
            multiplier *= 10;
            multiplier += arr[i];
        }
    }
    return maxVal * multiplier; // 6 * 543 = 3258
}
```

It turns out the my implementation is not correct because the highest product you can get out of this array would be:

```
63 * 54 = 3402
```

I think this part of the problem boils down to some sort of permutation problem where you try all possible combinations. Please note that libraries are not allowed. So in case you need some type of sorting, you have to implement it yourself. I would appreciate if the answer is in Java since it is my language of choice for this problem.

EDIT:

The value of each element in the array is always a positive single digit integer except for zero. Hence the constraint,

```
1 <= integer_in_array <= 9
```

Each integer could vary from 1 to 9 only. And the number of elements in the array varies from 3 to 8 only. The smallest array you could get would have 3 elements and the biggest would have 8 elements in it.

The question is how to get the highest possible product using the elements in the array. So, in my sample array, possible combinations would be:

```
63 * 54 = 3402 // Correct answer
6 * 543 = 3258 // My answer (wrong)
53 * 46 = 2438 
4 * 536 = 2144
36 * 54 = 1944
5 * 634 = 3170
```

Comment: how many integers should be multiplied? (not all of them, I guess, since all integers are positive)

Comment: @amazingsaluyot with your array `{6, 5, 4, 3}` what the expected output?

Comment: ah, he probably means putting multiplication operator between every adjacent elements and treat a whole array as two numbers: 6*543, 65*43, 654*3. so what's the problem with comparing all those combinations?

Comment: yes that's what is needed to be done. And it's not about simply putting the multiplication sign between elements. As we see from example, 63*54 is the answer and 6 3 5 4 is not an ordered array

Comment: personally I have no clue other than taking every possible permutation and put the multiplication sign between each adjacent pair of elements. In other words O (n! * n) . I wonder would I get the bonus for that : )

Comment: @mangusta: Once you have decided which of the digits go in each of the factors, _within_ each factor you should clearly have the largest digits first. So -- assuming we're looking for solutions with exactly two factors -- there are only 2^n possibilities to check (or actually half that many because the order of factors doesn't matter), which is eminently feasible when n is at most 8 ...

Comment: I have added some clarifications. I hope it makes the question clearer.

Comment: It’s clear now. Thank you for the edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy way: brute force to all combinations. Let's divide the array into 2 parts, so we want to create two largest number from those numbers.

```
public int maxProduct(int[]data) {
      Arrays.sort(data);//non-decreasing order
      int n = data.length;
      int result = 0; 
      for(int i = 0; i < (1 << n); i++){ 
          int a = 0;
          int b = 0;
          for(int j = n - 1; j >= 0; j--){
               if(((1 << j) & i) == 0){
                    a = a * 10 + data[j];
               }else{
                    b = b * 10 + data[j];
               }
          }
          result = Integer.max(result, a*b);
      }
      return result;
}
```

Time complexity : O(n*2 ^ n)

Comment: Let me see what's wrong, yah, you are right @OleV.V. Let's me fix that

Comment: Libraries are not allowed so "Integer.max(result, a * b)" would result in an error :(

Comment: `max` is just a simple function. You can do it within one line of code. Your requirement makes my code dirty, that I can't do. @amazingsaluyot

Comment: @OleV.V. yah man, I removed that part, definitely that is wrong, still thinking of better approach :)

Comment: I ran 10 000 000 random test examples. Your results agreed with those from my answer in all cases. I suppose that’s reassuring for both solutions.

Comment: @OleV.V. That's awesome man, so sad that I can only upvote you once.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s my go. I have no strict argument that it works correctly in all cases, nor that it’s the simplest possible solution. On the other hand I haven’t found any holes yet.

```
static int getProduct(int... arr) {
    // Should validate arr

    Arrays.sort(arr);

    int a = arr[arr.length - 1];
    int b = arr[arr.length - 2];
    for (int ix = arr.length - 3; ix >= 0; ix--) {
        int digit = arr[ix];
        // append d to either a or b depending on where it makes the greater product
        int candidate1 = (a * 10 + digit) * b;
        int candidate2 = a * (b * 10 + digit);
        if (candidate1 > candidate2) {
            a = a * 10 + digit;
        } else {
            b = b * 10 + digit;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("" + a + " * " + b + " = " + a * b);
    return a * b;
}
```

For testing purposes I have put in a `System.out.println` that you may not want to be there in your final method. Some example calls:

```
    getProduct(9, 8, 1);
    getProduct(9, 2, 1);
    getProduct(1, 2, 2, 1);
    getProduct(1, 2, 3, 9);
    getProduct(1, 2, 8, 9);
    getProduct(1, 7, 8, 9);
    getProduct(2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
    getProduct(1, 3, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7, 9);
```

Output from same:

> ```
> 9 * 81 = 729
> 9 * 21 = 189
> 21 * 21 = 441
> 91 * 32 = 2912
> 91 * 82 = 7462
> 91 * 87 = 7917
> 63 * 542 = 34146
> 9631 * 7743 = 74572833
> ```

Please start shooting…

**Edit:** I think that `a` is always constructed from the digits at indices `length - 1`, `length - 4`, `length - 6`, `length - 8`, and `b` from `length - 2`, `length - 3`, `length - 5`, `length - 7`, but limitied to the length of the array, of course. This observation may lead to code that is simpler (and performs a bit more efficiently), but where it’s even less obvious that it gives the best result.

Comment: Looks great +1. It will be awesome if there is a mathematical proof for this.

Comment: Agree, @PhamTrung, a proof would be awesome. A clever mathematician might be able to either prove or disprove. I am not going to myself, sorry.

Comment: @OleV.V. i think your answer is the best, and i agree : `A clever mathematician might be able to either prove or disprove.`